# Dotnet Core - resourceStream is timing out when read as an embedded resource

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an embedded resource containing a json file that has 19000 odd Australian suburbs. I have it in a related assembly in my solution build.

My issue is that when I check the variable "resourceStream" after getting the resource it has timed out..

[image]

The actual error close up:

```
resourceStream.ReadTimeout = 'resourceStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

Here is the code:

```
    using (var resourceStream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("JobsLedger.INITIALISATION.SUBURB.Initialisations.SuburbJSON.australianSuburbs.json"))
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var suburbs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BaseSuburb>>(jsonString);
    }
```

So it gets 4900 odd postcodes before timing out.. should get 19000.

The ones it gets are converted and work.. nice, but I actually need all of them :(

There must be a way to stop it from timing out. I noticed a post suggesting changing it to async but there are no await methods, it said, for GetManifestResourceStream.

Also this is on the resource stream.. not on the reader.. I think the reader would be fine to handle 18k records.

How do I get the "resourceStream" to run and actually get the whole file before timing out? or is this a problem with the file?

Comment: None of the errors you've shown indicate a timeout, it just says that 'timeouts are not supported on this stream'. If you give it more time does it complete?

Comment: Adding on to this, if it were *actually* timing out, you would almost certainly have malformed JSON

Comment: Good point.. did this for a csv file and it obtained all records.. with a json file it only picks up 5k records.

Comment: also.. how can I give it more time?